# Footer stick to bottom with adaptative layout (Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

I'm having a problem to stick my footer to bottom. I'm following the classic wrapper idea with an empty div that push the footer to the bottom. This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <section class="wrapper">
            <!--main content-->
            <div class="push"></div>  
        </section>

        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <!--footer content-->
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -13em;
}

.push {
    height: 13em;
    clear: both;
}

.footer{        
    padding: 20px 0;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
```

I used 13em for the height and margin sizes because is the size for the medium and large screens. 
This code works, but the problem starts when the layout has to adapt to extra-small and small sizes. Infact when the screen becomes smaller, the footer's height increase.

So my question is: how can i set a dynamic height to the `.push` div and to the margin of the wrapper? I want those values equal to the footer height.

I tried also some javascript but without success.

P.s. please don't tell me to set a static height for the footer (13em for example) because, as i said, i want an adaptative height.

**UPDATE**

I want something like this: http://ryanfait.com/html5-sticky-footer/

Comment: You might want to investigate using @media queries (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries , https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ )

Comment: @jeff i'm checking these links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a important part in the html, the body content, there is no content. I added a div with height and take a look

```
<body>
    <section class="wrapper">
        <!--main content-->
        <div class="push"></div>  
    </section>
    <div style="height:100%;min-height:100%;"></div>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <!--footer content-->
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Now its working as you want. Here is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/wgrLfxg3/12/

Take a look to the div I set height and min-height to 100%. Now put your content inside this div and it will work fine.

Comment: As i said to the other user: This can't help me, the footer will always remain to the bottom of the page during scroll, i want it to remain to the bottom only after the maximum scroll

Comment: But i appreciated the "amigo"!

Comment: Then you should edit your question as it says you are having a problem to stick my footer to bottom. and stick means stick

Comment: To be honest I dont think any of us understand what you want.

Comment: A sticky footer is another way of saying you want it fixed to the bottom of the viewport.

Comment: You can add the height to the container div too in css

Comment: Perfect, that was nearly what i wanted! So i accepted the answer "amigo"!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the wrapper and add this to your css instead:

```
.footer    {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;
}
```

Comment: This isn't what i asked, in this way the footer will remain stick to the bottom only if you know that the content is not so large to use scroll.

Comment: Just use css queries for the height issue on smaller screens (Responsive layout)